# Optimize indexed array summation

Tags: c++

I have the following C++ code:

```
const int N = 1000000
int id[N]; //Value can range from 0 to 9
float value[N];

// load id and value from an external source... 

int size[10] = { 0 };
float sum[10] = { 0 };
for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
{
    ++size[id[i]];
    sum[id[i]] += value[i];
}
```

How should I optimize the loop?

I considered using SSE to add every 4 floats to a sum and then after N iterations, the sum is just the sum of the 4 floats in the xmm register but this doesn't work when the source is indexed like this and needs to write out to 10 different arrays.

Comment: Just to make sure, in your real code are `size` and `sum` automatic variables as here? If they aren't (for instance if they're passed into your real routine by pointer or by reference), then there could be an artificial inefficiency introduced by the possibility of aliasing between `sum` and `value`, and/or `size` and `id`.

Comment: Would parallelization count as an optimization here?  i.e. partition the array into multiple sub-arrays, and hand each sub-array to a separate thread to iterate over, then combine the results at the end.  For large-enough arrays, that could give a good speedup, at least on a multicore machine.

Comment: Yes, size and sum are variables here like this. Partitioning sounds like a good idea, I will try memcpy to break them into quarters and run those in parallel.

Comment: @Dmi: don't break it into quarters with `memcpy`, just pass pointers/indexes to the 4 sections of the array.

Comment: @Dmi: by the way, if the float values being added together are of roughly comparable magnitude, then your `sum` will be horribly inaccurate due to loss of precision, before this code takes any significant time to run on a modern x86 processor. 1 million values is nothing, and beyond about 5 million summands `float` has lost precision. So parallelizing will actually give you a more accurate result, as well as being potentially faster...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This kind of loop is very hard to optimize using SIMD instructions. Not only isn't there an easy way in most SIMD instruction sets to do this kind of indexed read ("gather") or write ("scatter"), even if there was, this particular loop still has the problem that you might have two values that map to the same `id` in one SIMD register, e.g. when

```
id[0] == 0
id[1] == 1
id[2] == 2
id[3] == 0
```

in this case, the obvious approach (pseudocode here)

```
x = gather(size, id[i]);
y = gather(sum, id[i]);
x += 1; // componentwise
y += value[i];
scatter(x, size, id[i]);
scatter(y, sum, id[i]);
```

won't work either!

You can get by if there's a really small number of possible cases (e.g. assume that `sum` and `size` only had 3 elements each) by just doing brute-force compares, but that doesn't really scale.

One way to get this somewhat faster without using SIMD is by breaking up the dependencies between instructions a bit using unrolling:

```
int size[10] = { 0 }, size2[10] = { 0 };
int sum[10] = { 0 }, sum2[10] = { 0 };
for (int i = 0; i < N/2; i++) {
  int id0 = id[i*2+0], id1 = id[i*2+1];
  ++size[id0];
  ++size2[id1];
  sum[id0] += value[i*2+0];
  sum2[id1] += value[i*2+1];
}

// if N was odd, process last element
if (N & 1) {
  ++size[id[N]];
  sum[id[N]] += value[N];
}

// add partial sums together
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  size[i] += size2[i];
  sum[i] += sum2[i];
}
```

Whether this helps or not depends on the target CPU though.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you are calling id[i] twice in your loop. You could store it in a variable, or a register int if you wanted to.

```
register int index;
for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
{
index = id[i];
++size[index];
sum[index] += value[i];
}
```

The MSDN docs state this about register:

> The register keyword specifies that
>   the variable is to be stored in a
>   machine register.. Microsoft Specific
>
> The compiler does not accept user
>   requests for register variables;
>   instead, it makes its own register
>   choices when global
>   register-allocation optimization (/Oe
>   option) is on. However, all other
>   semantics associated with the register
>   keyword are honored.

Comment: The register keyword is pretty pointless as any optimiser will move the counter into a register anyway ...

Comment: If the compiler doesn't do this anyway, bin it (or switch optimization on).

Comment: As you even quote, the "stick this into a register" semantics of the "register" keyword are ignored by VC++ (and almost all other current C++ compilers). And unless the compiler suspects there's aliasing (i.e. `++size[index]` might overwrite memory used by `id`), it will do such common subexpression elimination automatically.

Comment: Using register id like this increased performance about 15%, VC++ 2010 with optimizations on.

Comment: @Dmi: Have you got optimisation turned on??

Comment: @Dmi: I'm genuinely shocked that it makes any difference ... I've tried using the keyword loads in the past and all it has ever done is negatively impact performance.  I've always assumed because I am reducing the number of registers available.  Admittedly I've never tried optimising such a simple loop before ...

Comment: Then the compiler *does* think size might alias id :)

Comment: @Fabian: Fair game. Would you not get the same performance boost just by storing it in an "int index" rather than a "register int index"?

Comment: Yes you would. Don't have VC2010 here to test it though.

Comment: @Fabian: Yeah I would personally have stored it in a const int inside the loop rather than a variable outside the loop (It looks cleaner in my opinion) and I'd doubt it would make any difference to overall speed compared to the keeping it out of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Something you can do is to compile it with the `-S` flag (or equivalent if you aren't using gcc) and compare the various assembly outputs using `-O`, `-O2`, and `-O3` flags.  One common way to optimize a loop is to do some degree of unrolling, for (a very simple, naive) example:

```
int end = N/2;
int index = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < end; ++i)
{
    index = 2 * i;
    ++size[id[index]];
    sum[id[index]] += value[index];
    index++;
    ++size[id[index]];
    sum[id[index]] += value[index];
}
```

which will cut the number of `cmp` instructions in half.  However, any half-decent optimizing compiler will do this for you.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it will make much difference?  The likelihood is that the loading of "id from an external source" will take significantly longer than adding up the values.

Do not optimise until you KNOW where the bottleneck is.

*Edit in answer to the comment*:  You misunderstand me.  If it takes 10 seconds to load the ids from a hard disk then the fractions of a second spent on processing the list are immaterial in the grander scheme of things.  Lets say it takes 10 seconds to load and 1 second to process:

You optimise the processing loop so it takes 0 seconds (almost impossible but its to illustrate a point) then it is STILL taking 10 seconds.  11 Seconds really isn't that ba a performance hit and you would be better off focusing your optimisation time on the actual data load as this is far more likely to be the slow part.

In fact it can be quite optimal to do double buffered data loads.  ie you load buffer 0, then you start the load of buffer 1.  While buffer 1 is loading you process buffer 0.  when finished start the load of the next buffer while processing buffer 1 and so on.  this way you can completely amortise the cost of procesing.

*Further edit*:  In fact your best optimisation would probably come from loading things into a set of buckets that eliminate the "id[i]" part of te calculation.  You could then simply offload to 3 threads where each uses SSE adds.  This way you could have them all going simultaneously and, provided you have at least a triple core machine, process the whole data in a 10th of the time.  Organising data for optimal processing will always allow for the best optimisation, IMO.

Comment: Very sure... skipping every other value gives 40% performance increase, skipping 75% values give 80% performance increase.

Comment: Sure it will increase performance of the loop, but is this loop the bottleneck of your program?

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood you. Yes, the performance increase I refer to is for the whole program, not locally. :)

Comment: @Dmi:  What machine are you working on?  I'd be interested to see all of your code because those figures do not make sense.  Memsetting both your arrays would not be as quick as you are suggesting above ...

Comment: Q6600. 
Time with adding all: 7.2 seconds
Time with skipping every other i: 4.9 seconds
Time with skipping all except 1 in 4: 2.8 seconds

Edit to say: Usually, the entire array isn't modified in memory, maybe 5-30% is but I don't have a way to determine which is modified right now. That's why it's not the speed problem.

Comment: @Dmi:  I'd still like to see the rest of the code.  Otimising without context is a very strange thing to do ...

Comment: Show us how you're getting those numbers. What is your overall program that this loop is such a big part of it?

Comment: There's a whole lot of code, the reason why it's not the bottleneck is the source array gets certain elements chainged (5-30%), then I have to compute the size and sum of each value in the histogram each time.

Comment: Timings are calculated with QueryPerformanceCounter, 10000 iterations of modifying inputs + calculating this loop.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your target machine and compiler, see if you have the _mm_prefetch intrinsic and give it a shot.  Back in the Pentium D days, pre-fetching data using the asm instruction for that intrinsic was a real speed win as long as you were pre-fetching a few loop iterations before you needed the data.

See [here](ftp://download.intel.com/intelpress/excerpts/excerpt_swcb1.pdf) (Page 95 in the PDF) for more info from Intel.

Answer (score 0):

This computation is trivially parallelizable; just add

#pragma omp parallel_for reduction(+:size,+:sum) schedule(static)

immediately above the loop if you have OpenMP support (-fopenmp in GCC.)  However, I would not expect much speedup on a typical multicore desktop machine; you're doing so little computation per item fetched that you're almost certainly going to be constrained by memory bandwidth.

If you need to perform the summation several times for a given id mapping (i.e. the value[] array changes more often than id[]), you can halve your memory bandwidth requirements by pre-sorting the value[] elements into id order and eliminating the per-element fetch from id[]:

for (i = 0, j = 0, k = 0; j < 10; sum[j] += tmp, j++)

for (k += size[j], tmp = 0; i < k; i++)

```
  tmp += value[i];
```

Comment: OpenMP reduction doesn't work for arrays, it only works if size and sum are scalar types.